# Remove development files from ubuntu

Tags: package-management

I was cleaning up for some hard disk space and I remembered installing a bunch of packages with a `dev` on it. It was for compiling some programs but I don't do it anymore. Is there anyway of removing them without manually picking them out in synaptic, it is very stressing to see a long list of packages with a `dev` on it

Comment: Use the command line and find out which dev packages you did install manually and which were pre-installed (see apt logs). `apt purge $list_of_packages` is easier than ticking the packages in synaptic.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this from the terminal to get a list of installed dev packages.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
dpkg -l | grep ii | grep \\-dev
```